# mysql find date based result by year

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(case when c_gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) as Male, SUM(case when c_gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) as Female , count(*) as tot , FROM_UNIXTIME(c_admissionDate, '%Y') as year FROM `student` where FROM_UNIXTIME(`c_admissionDate`, '%m') group by year
```

my data 
student table

```
gender   admissiondate     leaving date
 male     1375813800         1407781800   
 female   1344277800         1408473000
 female   1344277800         null
 female   1344277800         1407781800
```

want to find the sum of count

sum of count = sum of All admission date by year count - sum of leaving date by year count

i need result like

```
year male female admission leaving total
2014  2      1      3         1      2
2013  10     2     12         3      9
```

Comment: Add your expected result set

Comment: hi Khalid @ resultset updated

Comment: Have you tried grouping by the year & performing your aggregate operations on that? I haven't worked with UNIX timestamps much but DATE_FORMAT might accept it, then you could format the date to just use the year in your GROUP BY.

Comment: @DhanushBala According to your expected result set calculation of `admission`,`leaving` isn't clear can you elaborate the how `admission`,`leaving` will be calculated ?

Comment: SELECT SUM(case when st.c_gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) as male, SUM(case when st.c_gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) as female ,  SUM(case when  FROM_UNIXTIME(st.c_leavingDate, '%Y') is not null then 1 else 0 end) as leaving , count(st.id) as tot ,  FROM_UNIXTIME(st.c_admissionDate, '%Y') as year  FROM `student` st  group by year order by  FROM_UNIXTIME(st.c_leavingDate, '%Y')

Comment: @DhanushBala could you show what out put you got by your current query?